# Previous/next file with indexOf jquery?

Tags: jquery, menu, pagination, load, indexof

I am trying to create a Previous/Next gallery style menu that loads files from different directories (based on window url).
I use php include for the menu (on all pages) and then jquery to load the script on each page but the problem is the if/else runs from start each time, messing the structure. What is a better way of doing this? (basically when the code runs again it doesn't move to the next else-if to correspond/sync to current window url)

```
        if (window.location.href.indexOf("page1") > -1){
            $(".next").attr('href', "portfolio/page2/");
        }
        else if (window.location.href.indexOf('page2')){
            $(".previous").attr('href', "portfolio/page1/");
            $(".next").attr('href', "portfolio/page3/");
        }
        else if (window.location.href.indexOf('page3')){
            $(".previous").attr('href', "portfolio/page2/");
            $(".next").attr('href', "portfolio/page4/");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I had to add > -1 or != -1 on each else if statement for this to work:

```
window.location.href.indexOf("page2") > -1
```